# Obtain class type/name from a parametrized type in runtime

Tags: json, scala, generics, manifest

I am trying to build a generic CRUD interface that receives an element, searches for an implicit CRUD implementation from an evidence and also serialize the necessary object based on the parametrized type.

The code goes as follow:

```
 private def createElement[T <: AnyRef](element: String)
               (implicit ev: ResourceManager[T], m: Manifest[T]): Response = Try {
   val e = Serializer.fromJson(element, m.runtimeClass)
   ev.create(e, persistence)
   ResponseBuilder.newBuilder().status(202).build()
}.getOrElse(ResponseBuilder.newBuilder().status(412).build())
```

As you can see. I receive a String, an evidence of a ResourceManager that implements the create method and a Manifest. When trying to serialize i make sure that the T type is of AnyRef but that is not the issue.

The problem is that `m.runtimeClass` returns Class[_] instead of Class[T].

My question is, if manifest does do what i want, how can i do this without explicitly passing the class name or whatever?

Thank you!

Comment: Any reason you are stuck with `Manifest` instead of `ClassTag`? the former is deprecated...

Comment: .asInstanceOf[T] on the runtimeclass

Comment: @ALec I saw Class tag and even tried some implementations with it but I could not get what I want.  Do you have anything?

Comment: @RafaelSaraiva what happens if you replace `Manifest` with `ClassTag` and add `import scala.reflect.ClassTag`?

Comment: @Alec tbh both Manifest and ClassTag(or TypeTag?) do not look like are going to be the solution for my problem. Neither is asInstanceOf[T] for sure! I am not suffering for a type erasure problem i believe, all i want is to obtain the classOf the parametrized type.

Comment: @Alec @Maxim I did some digging and realized what i required was the structure WeakTypedTag. However, since i need a java.lang.class[T] i had to do the following ugly code. `Serializer.fromJson(element, Class.forName(tag.tpe.toString).asInstanceOf[Class[T]])`. Any ideas for a cleaner solution?